# angular.js: select textearea's content upon modification

Tags: javascript, events, angularjs

I want to know if it's possible to select a textarea's content when it gets modified. In jQuery, I'd do the following:

```
$("texarea").on("change", function (e) {
    $(this).select(); // the content gets selected for copy/cut operations
});
```

I know it's a bad practice to directly manipulate DOM elements from within an angular controller, so if you know how I can do this cleanly, I'd be happy to learn how!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do the following, attach an event handler to your textfield element using `onblur` and `onfocus` attributes. Write two functions for each as follows:

`onfocus` get the initial content of the textfield
`onblur` get the final content and compare to the initial content if there is a difference the run the select function

If you want it to be in real time your could also use `onkeyup` and `onkeydown`